# cambiar el valor del check box cuando selecciono un combo box

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un problema y no se como arreglarlo
mi problema consiste que tengo dos checkbox y un combobox(select) 
lo que yo quiero es que cuando selecciono el combo box se cambie el valor de select con js.

me explico mejor, mi checkbox con valor de 5000 y el combobox(select)con los valores de seleccione, 5000, 10000 ,lo que necesito es que cuando yo seleccione el checkbox, el combobox(select)se cambie de valor a 5000 automaticamente.

no se como hacer la funcion en js

este es mi codigo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>

</head>
<body>

<form class="insp_p" action=" " method="post">

<fieldset class="cabezal_p"> 
    <br>
        <input type="Checkbox" name="5000" id="5000"> 5000
        <input type="Checkbox" name="10000" id="10000" > 10000
        <br>    
        <input type="Checkbox" name="Checkbox1" id="Checkbox1" value="1" class="Checkbox">
        <label class="INSPECCIONES">CAMBIO DE ACEITE Y FILTRO DEL MOTOR</label>
        <select width="100px" id="intervalo1" name="intervalo1" class="selectp">
        <option>Seleccione</option>
        <option>5000</option>
        <option>10000</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" id="comentario1" name="comentario1" placeholder="comentario" class="comentariop">
        <br>    
</fieldset>

</form>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero haber entendido bien lo que necesitas hacer. Dicho esto, lo que podes hacer es usar el evento **change** para saber si cambió el valor del checkbox y luego seteas el valor a seleccionar en el combobox

```
$('#5000').change(function () {
      var chk = $("#5000")
      var chckseleccionado = chk[0].checked
      if (chckseleccionado) {
        $("#intervalo1").val("5000");
      }
  });
```

Comment: mmuchas gracias amigo me servicio mucho

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input:radio[name=select]").click(function() {
            $("#intervalo1 > option").attr("selected",false);
            $("#intervalo1 option[value="+ parseInt($("input:radio[name=select]:checked").val()) +"]").attr("selected",true);
        });
    });

</script>

        <form class="insp_p" action=" " method="post">

        <fieldset class="cabezal_p"> 
            <br>
                <input type="radio" name="select" value="5000">5000
                <input type="radio" name="select" value="10000">10000
                <br>    
                <select width="100px" id="intervalo1" name="intervalo1" class="selectp">
                    <option>Seleccione</option>
                    <option value=5000>5000</option>
                    <option value=10000>10000</option>
                </select>
            <br>    
        </fieldset>

    </form>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, es importante comentar que es lo que realiza el código y de que forma ayudaría a solucionar el problema planteado en la pregunta, revisa [answer], saludos.